# I want result with distinct value of one field from mongodb using spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want result with distinct value of one field from mongodb using spring data. My code is

```
Query query = new Query();

    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("to.toId").in(toIdList));
    query.fields().include("from");
    query.fields().include("fromName");
    query.fields().include("sentTime");
    query.fields().include("hasAttachment");
    newMessages = mongoTemplate.find(query, NewMessage.class);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use distinct instead of find:

```
db.mycollection.distinct('fieldname', query)
```

Using SpringData the syntax should be something like this:

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection).distinct(key, query)
```

Comment: Great... thank you... just a note: query it isn't a Query object, but a DBObject, such as a "BasicDBObject" with key and value of the "query" you want to execute.