# MongoDB: How do I retrieve a filtered set of results and a related collection that’s filtered in different ways before being counted?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a collection `C1` which looks like this (simplified):

```
[
  // ID and other irrelevant fields omitted
  {
    "name": "A",
    "related": "Y",
    "special": "foo",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-02-07T19:36:52.757+02:00")
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "related": "Z",
    "special": "bar",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-02-07T19:36:52.757-06:00")
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "related": "X",
    "special": "baz",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-02-07T19:36:52.757+01:00")
  },
  {
    "name": "D",
    "related": "Z",
    "special": "quux",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-02-07T19:36:52.757+01:00")
  },
  // ...more records omitted...
]
```

And a collection `C2` which looks like this (again, simplified):

```
[
  // ID and other irrelevant fields omitted
  {
    "name": "X",
    "total": 500
  },
  {
    "name": "Y",
    "total": 200
  },
  {
    "name": "Z",
    "total": 10
  },
  // ...more records omitted...
]
```

How can I, in a single query, retrieve a filtered set of records in `C1` (e.g. `{ "special": "foo" }`) with each record having a field `c2` containing the matching records from `C2` (`C1.related` being equal to `C2.name`) in addition to:

- a field `lowCount` being the count of all matching records from `C2` where `{ total: { $lte: 100 } }`
- a field `midCount` being the count of all matching records from `C2` where `{ total: { $lte: 500, $gt: 100 } }`
- a field `highCount` being the count of all matching records from `C2` where `{ total: { $gt: 500 } }`

I realize that the database structure is awkward for what needs to be done, but I came in long after that was finalized and it can’t be overhauled at this point. The actual code is written in Java using Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MongoDb aggregation.

```
db.c1.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "special": "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "c2",
      localField: "related",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "c2"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      lowCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$c2",
            cond: {
              $lte: [
                "$$this.total",
                100
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      midCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$c2",
            cond: {
              $lte: [
                "$$this.total",
                500
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      highCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$c2",
            cond: {
              $gte: [
                "$$this.total",
                500
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jj-8kayziBq)

Spring Data allows to aggregate with `MongoTemplate` class (implements MongoOperations). Take a look how to transform this pipeline into Spring syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60011133/3710490)